# from pyspark.sql.functions import max

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

trying to get the following "from pyspark.sql.functions import col,max " using version 3.0.0 and it does not work. Has this been changed in new version?

Comment: No, it should be the same. See the docs: https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0-preview2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#module-pyspark.sql.functions There should be some other issue here.

Comment: No changes in new version, please provide error stacktrace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to suggest that you don't import directly, since it will override python built-in functions with same name like max, sum, etc.

So, you should import like - 
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

and now you can use it like - F.max()